# How to delete an recipe in form of JSON from a server?

Tags: ios, curl, nsurlsession, http-delete, nsurlsessiontask

I write a code that get recipes in form of JSON from a server and present it into a UItable.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/recipes"];
    [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@" Token token=\"3f71235466468b7f7\""}];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    [[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        recipes= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
       [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
      ] resume];
```

This server is written in Ruby. Now I want to write a request to delete a recipe. Here it is the instruction of my server . It said that I should use following curl to delete a recipes:

Delete recipes DELETE: /recipes/:id In Curl it would be something like that:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="0b774d575632b"' -X DELETE http://domain.com/recipes/22
```

Does anybody know how can I implement delete method?

Comment: it's just an http request... process it like you would most any other request.

Comment: @MarcB  
thx, should I implement the request like when I post sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `dataTaskWithURL:`, which only allows GET requests, you should use [`dataTaskWithRequest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:).

Create an [`NSMutableURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/HTTPMethod) with the appropriate URL, and set its `HTTPMethod` property to @"DELETE". You can then use that request in your `NSURLSession`.